# How to rotate and spin a cone in a cylinder

Tags: animation, keyframes, graph-editor, timeline

Im trying to get my animation of this cone rotating around a cylinder to also spin along is local Z axis while is rotating around the cylinder, how could i do this, ive tried setting new keyframes with each key being rotated -90 degrees but then i get some funky results

[image]

[image]

[image]

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ktQ0dBY6P-Hp7XBbTyE927wioxVHUd9h/view?usp=drive_link

^^^video of how i have it right now, but I want it to spin with the rotation.

Comment: parent it to an empty that will rotate 360°?

Comment: How would i do that, im also jumping back into animation so ive forgotten a lot.

Comment: Do you want it to look like it’s rolling along the inside, or scraping against it?

Comment: I want it to roll without slipping, keeping it in line with the rotation its going in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an empty at the center of the cylinder, parent the cone to the empty:

[image]

Open the *Dope Sheet*, at frame 1 create a first keyframe for the cone, at frame X create a second that is a 180° rotation for example, press <kbd>T</kbd> in order to choose a linerar interpolation, and also press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> to create a linear extrapolation. Do the same for the empty, result:

[image]

Comment: ah ok, i do want it spinning around the tip of the cone tho, does anything change if I make the axis of ratation the tip?

Comment: You can put the empty at the tip of the cone if this is what you ask, then parent the cone to the empty, but it won't change anything in terms of result but maybe i misunderstand?

Comment: Yea now its just rotating in place, If you look back at the video you see the cone is on its point, I placed an empty at the tip, parented the cone to the empty, then remade the smooth path, then I selected the empty and rotated it 90 degrees in the Z also the rotation the cone was moving and it is now stuck in place.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iTy-z0gvN9Qh0k4jrpjobrtyJRhysGBo/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Chris has given an answer, is it what you want? Or please show a storyboard

Answer (score 0):

i would do it like this:

rotate the cone that it "leans" already to one side of the cylinder

[image]

Then just animate the z rotation like this:

[image]

it's linear extrapolation

[image]

[image]

Comment: How would you animate the z like that, all ive seen is adding keyframes